# RTSP youtube link

Tags: android, youtube, rtsp

I have gone all over google and am having trouble getting the rtsp link from a youtube video give the VIDEO_ID.

I am confused on how to use that id and then parse google for the link.

Thank you for your time and and effort.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this [blog entry](http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2008/10/getting-rtsp-streams-from-youtube-api.html), maybe its a starting point. If you follow on of the `<id>` links you get another format where you should find the rtsp link.

EDIT:
after going through what WarrenFaith posted. PROPS TO HIM

this is how you get a rtsp link.

1. make a request

   - http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/VIDEO_ID
2. parse that data for the 3gp content

   - It also provides you with the rating and all that good stuff that you may want.

hope that helps you guys

Comment: "Q-GLuydiMe4" id will not open through this way

Comment: Q-GLuydiMe4 id will not open through this way ? why is it, have you know this issue ?

Comment: yes, it is running well but RTSP is not generated by this id. I have checked and found that app control is like "Syndication of this video was restricted". and this is reason but I need to sort this thing. Is there any way to allow this permission in android

Comment: if you use a nintendo dsi user agent the video will be a link to the rtsp video. However it is extremely compressed

Comment: This has been disabled

Answer (score 2):

A short and simple way of getting the rtsp link, should be easily portable to any platform.

```
String video_id = "1FJHYqE0RDg";
String gdata = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
String youtube_response = Util.getUrlResponse(gdata+video_id); // just a simple HTTP GET
String rtsp_link = "rtsp:"+ StringUtils.split(StringUtils.split(youtube_response, "rtsp:")[1], ".3gp")[0] + ".3gp";
```

Comment: "Q-GLuydiMe4" id will not open through this way. Why ?

Comment: Q-GLuydiMe4 id will not open through this way ? can you explain ?

Comment: maybe the video has other restrictions on it.

Comment: so, from our side we can not play this video but this restriction is not in iOs and other android apps. how they are using this thing. I am bit of curious about this ???? have you any idea how to resolve it ?

Comment: not really, we can only see what google exposes. Not sure why this video doesn't show rtsp link like others.You could explore youtube api a bit deeper to find the reason.

Answer (score 1):

without a program if u want to fetch a YOUTUBE RTSP link then

1. GO TO www.youtube.com
2. select the video whose rtsp link u want....
3. go to the url of that video.....
4. fetch the id from the url i.e. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**6acRHWnfZAE**
   ((the id of the starts from "=" and goes upto the end... in the above case 6acRHWnfZAE is the id of the video in the example
5. now open http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ and after this url paste the id of your video......
6. a page will open
7. now search for the **media:content** in that page
   there will be atleast 3  **attribute
   one will be **HTTP** n the other two will be **rtsp** (**format 1** n **format 6**);
   as per my experience **format 1** is only for video,,,, n format 6** is for audio n video both

Comment: Response from youtube: No longer available