# Playing YoutTube's video in custom player

Tags: android, youtube

I need:

- a HD quality video.
- custom controls on player (play, pause, etc.).
- play video in my activity.

I've tried:

- YouTubePlayerView (from YouTube API) - it works well, but it has default youtube's controls, so I cannot use it.
- [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716146/rtsp-youtube-link/9837008#9837008) - it provides low quality video, but it is not suitable as well.

Is it possible to override YouTubePlayerView controls or play youtube's video in custom player?